# How to delete/remove Xcode DocC

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to remove "Scratch" below from my Xcode's "Developer Documentation". Any of you guys know how to remove it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your project, in "Product" menu, tap on "Show Build Folder in Finder", go to Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator,
delete "Scratch.doccarchive" file, close and reopen your project